# iPhone Accessory warning - without any accessory

Tags: iphone, accessories, error

I am getting following error:

[image]

Previously I connected iPhone headphone/handsfree. It was working fine. Now, I disconnected my headphone/handsfree & my iPhone started giving warning as follows.

I am not sure what's wrong with the phone. I have restarted iPhone many many times, but anything didn't work. I am not able to talk with iPhone without handsfree. iPhone forcing me to use handsfree.

Comment: I thought this might be a problem with a jailBreak os. I removed entire os & installed a new OS - 3.1.3 ( I have 2G ). But even in newly installed os, its prompting me same. I lost everything due to iOS installation ( didn't take backup - my mistake :'( )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is caused by circuit shortening on the iPhone dock connector. This means that the iPhone detects some kind of an accessory is connected (pin shortened), but cannot verify that it's genuine. Try cleaning it with compressed air.